# How to Calculate Total Price Per Month in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to calculate total Prise per month.

i have a database where I save data every minute.

```
TIME                    KWHI        EUR
2023-12-02 23:00:15     8852.892    12.8040
2023-12-02 22:59:13     8852.892    13.4496
2023-12-02 22:58:11     8852.892    13.4496
2023-12-02 22:57:09     8852.892    13.4496

SELECT  TIME,
     ((max(KWHI) - min(KWHI)) * EUR)/100 AS HOUREUR
FROM LOG WHERE 1    
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(TIME),
    MONTH(TIME),
    DAY(TIME),
    HOUR(TIME)
ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 24
```

in this query i get amount of one hour

the price **EUR** changes every hour

I would like to calculate by one month?

Comment: NB your expression `max(KWHI) - min(KWHI)` only covers changes that happen between the highest and lowest readings within the same hour.  If there is a change in KWHI between the last reading of one hour and the first reading of the next, that won't be captured in your expression.  That might be how you intend it, but just thought I'd flag it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by wrapping your existing query in an outer `SELECT` that aggregates over a month:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(TIME), '%Y-%m') AS 'MONTH',
    SUM(HOUREUR) AS 'MONTHEUR'
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(TIME) AS TIME,
        ((max(KWHI) - min(KWHI)) * MAX(EUR))/100 AS HOUREUR
    FROM LOG
    WHERE 1    
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR(TIME),
        MONTH(TIME),
        DAY(TIME),
        HOUR(TIME)
) hourly
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(TIME),
    MONTH(TIME)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

If you want to account for changes in KWHI between the last reading of one hour and the first reading of the next, I would propose a slighly simpler calculation.  Instead of using `max(KWHI) - min(KWHI)` over a group, I suggest using a window function per row.  That then means it easier to group over any time range you need.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(logsums.TIME), '%Y-%m') AS 'MONTH',
    SUM(logsums.EURSUM) AS 'EURSUM'
FROM (
    SELECT
        TIME,
        EUR * (KWHI - LEAD(KWHI) OVER (ORDER BY TIME DESC)) / 100 AS 'EURSUM'
    FROM LOG
) logsums
GROUP BY
    YEAR(logsums.TIME),
    MONTH(logsums.TIME)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

select coalesce(sum(e.amount), 0) as expense, m.month
from (select '01' as month union all
select '02' as month union all
select '03' as month union all
select '04' as month union all
select '05' as month union all
select '06' as month union all
select '07' as month union all
select '08' as month union all
select '09' as month union all
select '10' as month union all
select '11' as month union all
select '12' as month
) m left join
expenses e
on year(e.date) = 2019 and
DATE_FORMAT(e.date,'%m') = m.month
group by m.month;
Here is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I can't see that this answer relates to the question at all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).